# Error "No value for argument 'b' in method call" while generating graph

Tags: python, graph

I have to generate an eulerian graph and later print out it's path and I've decided to use Python 3.x . However I can't get the graph generator to work. My code so far:

```
from random import randint
def generateGraph(n,intensity):
    res=[[] for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        res[n][n]=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            if (randint(100)<intensity):
                res[i][j],res[j][i]=1,1
    for i in range(n-1):
        deg=0
        for j in range(n-1):
            if (res[i][j]==1):
                deg+=1
        if(deg%2!=0):
            x=randint(n-i-1)+i+1
            if (res[i][x]>0):
                res[x][i],res[i][x]=0,0
            else:
                res[i][x],res[x][i]=1,1
    return res
result=['1',]
def Euler(v,g1):
    for y in range(len(g1)):
        if (g1[v][y]==1):
            g1[v][y],g1[y][v]=0,0
            Euler(y,g1)
            result.append(str(v+1))
    return result
graph=generateGraph(10,30)
Euler(0,graph)
print (result)
```

Disregarding the graph connectivity for now, I'm getting the error in title in lines:

```
if (randint(100)<intensity)
```

and

```
x=randint(n-i-1)+i+1
```

I've tried looking up online for solutions but so far I've found none. I appriciate any help regarding this topic.

Comment: That's not a Python error. The error you'd get from running this code is an IndexError, because line 4 creates a list of empty lists and you then try to assign to (non-existent) elements inside those empty lists.

Comment: @DanielRoseman an oversight in code on my part that's been corrected. Thank you. Still something clogs the generation.